# Pass data from a Node.js server to a socket.io app

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have this very simple app:

```
// Require HTTP module (to start server) and Socket.IO
var http = require('http'), 
    io = require('socket.io'),
    url  = require('url');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 
  req.on('data', function(data){
    console.log('Received Data');
  })
});
server.listen(3000);

// Create a Socket.IO instance, passing it our server
var socket = io.listen(server);

// Add a connect listener
socket.on('connection', function(client){ 

  server.on('data',function(event){ 
     client.send(url.search);
     console.log('Received Data from socket app');
  });

  client.on('disconnect',function(){
    console.log('Server has disconnected');
  });

});
```

I need to curl the node server to pass it some post data, then i would like this data to be handed to the socket.io app so that it can feed back to the currently connected clients.

Is there anyway to accomplish that ?

Many thanks,

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Comment: @adam From a PHP script, when this data arrive to the node server i'd  like all connected client to be notified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `socket` that you get from

```
var socket = io.listen(server);
```

you can always call `emit` on this to send a message to all connected clients. So in your http server, you can `emit` the posted data:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 
  var body = '';
  req.on('data', function(data){
    console.log('Received Data');
    body += data;
  });
  req.on('end', function() {
    // Emit the data to all clients
    socket.emit('foo message', body);
  });
});
```